# Magento CLI Install Error Megento_Catalog

Tags: magento2.3, installation, cli, setup

I'm trying to install Magento 2.3 from the terminal and I find the following error, does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

```
In PatchApplier.php line 170:
                                                                                                                                                                                                
  Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallDefaultCategories for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message: Invalid entity_type specified: catalog_category  
                                                                                                                                                                                                

In Config.php line 449:
                                                   
  Invalid entity_type specified: catalog_category
```

I have seen that increasing php memory works for some people, but in my case that doesn't work.

Comment: didi you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't found the solution

Comment: Removing the algolia module fixed in my magento installation

Comment: does anybody got the solution?